# Is void* necessary apart from memory allocation related stuff

Tags: c++, void-pointers

Is `void*` necessary apart from memory allocation related stuff in C++?
Can you give me an example?

Comment: Well, memory allocation **is** a very important part of the language...

Comment: I am NOT saying memory allocation is not important, it's very important in c++. Just wondering if there is any other frequent usage...

Comment: Yes, I understand. I just wanted to suggest that void pointers might make an appearance more often than you're aware of, e.g. any time you say `std::vector`.

Comment: Are you referring to the vector grow internally ?

Comment: `void*` is the return type of any `operator new()` and any allocator's allocation function, which is used by almost all standard containers, so there's plenty of void pointing under the hood.

Comment: Yes, I knew that, anywhere using memory allocation should be involving void* under the hood.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Logging memory addresses

If you want to output a pointer using iostreams (e.g. for logging) then going via `void*` is the only way of ensuring `operator<<` hasn't been overloaded in some crazy way.

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, foo*) {
  return out<<"it's a trap!";
}

int main() {
  foo bar;
  foo *ptr = &bar;

  std::cout << ptr << std::endl;
  std::cout << static_cast<void*>(ptr) << std::endl;
}
```

---

### Testing iostream status

iostreams overload `operator void*` as a status check so that syntax like `if (stream)` or `while (stream)` is a short hand way of testing the stream status.

---

### Template meta programming

You might want to use `void*` with template metaprogramming sometimes as a reduced catch all, e.g. with SFINAE tricks, but more often than not there's a nicer way around it using a partial specialisation of one form or another.

---

### Accessing most derived pointer

As Alf pointed out in the comments `dynamic_cast<void*>` is also useful for getting at the most derived type in a heirarchy, e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>

struct other {
  virtual void func() = 0;
  int c;
};

struct foo {
  virtual void func() { std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; }
  int a;
};

struct bar : foo, other {
  virtual void func() { std::cout << "bar" << std::endl; }
  int b;
};

namespace {
  void f(foo *ptr) {
    ptr->func();
    std::cout << ptr << std::endl;
    std::cout << dynamic_cast<void*>(ptr) << std::endl;
  }

  void g(other *ptr) {
    ptr->func();
    std::cout << ptr << std::endl;
    std::cout << dynamic_cast<void*>(ptr) << std::endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  foo a;
  bar b;
  f(&a);
  f(&b);
  g(&b);
}
```

Gives:

```
foo
0xbfb815f8
0xbfb815f8
bar
0xbfb815e4
0xbfb815e4
bar
0xbfb815ec
0xbfb815e4
```

On my system.

---

### Exceptions

§ 15.3.1 states:

> The exception-declaration shall not denote a pointer or reference to
>   an incomplete type, other than void*, `const void*`, volatile void*, or
>   const volatile void*.

So it seems to be the only legal way of catching a pointer to an incomplete type is via `void*`. (Although I think there's possibly bigger issues if you actually needed to use that)

---

### Legacy C uses

There are a lot of "legacy" C uses for `void*` for storing pointers to data without knowing what it is, but in new C++ code there is almost always a better way of expressing the same functionality.

Comment: Also, `dynamic_cast<void*>(p)` is the only general way to get at the most derived object.

Comment: Can you give an example of a situation where void* is *neccessary* in template meta programming?

Comment: @Dennis - I can't think of an example that isn't too contrived which is why I didn't include any. My thinking was a 3-way "what is it?" type of thing where the outcomes could be Specific type, pointer or "other", i.e. `T*`, `void*`, `...`, but I'm aware that to describe it as *necessary* even for that is quite a stretch. That doesn't mean that there isn't a good example though, and it's certainly something I would say has a place in any box of tricks for meta programming problems.

Answer (score 2):

No it isn't. It's only an idiom to refer to non typed memory

Comment: I also think it is useful to avoid accidental pointer arithmetics that you don't want to do.

Comment: I think that I agree with this answer the most when it comes to the **best** way to write code (should always use static typing for everything) combined with the understanding that we're only talking about **storage** rather than using it for e.g. conversions or pointer-address-specific type stuff.

Answer (score 2):

external libraries use them often (esp. in C).

in this case, i'll usually hide the use of these libraries (or the more dangerous portions). i hide them by writing interfaces around them (like wrapping). the interfaces i write serve to introduce type safety into the program. in this case, `void*` may be required, but at least it's hidden and restricted to a method or callback.

Comment: I would have said it was less typesafe compared to using a pointer to a declared but not defined struct since *anything* could be passed in by accident instead!

Answer (score 2):

`void*` is frequently used for callbacks.

> Callbacks are generally implemented in the C language using function
>   pointers and auxiliary user-defined data passed as a void pointer for
>   genericity.

[[from here](http://www.crystalclearsoftware.com/cgi-bin/boost_wiki/wiki.pl?Generalizing_C-Style_Callbacks)]

Of course, this is not type-safe, so people come up with ways to wrap this kind of thing, [like here](http://ccan.ozlabs.org/info/typesafe_cb.html).

Comment: It makes sense for C, but it's 'legacy' at best in C++

Comment: @awoodland: it's a little bit more than legacy, I think. If you want to do type erasure of stateful callbacks, like `boost::function` does with functors, then I expect there's some `void*` buried in there somewhere. But you'd want to avoid the function pointer / user data pair in public interfaces, of course.

Answer (score 1):

One situation where you might want to use void is when passing around data buffers, such as in this function:

```
void loadData(void* data, std::size_t size)
```

A lot of code passes buffers through a char-pointer instead of a void-pointer because, typically, buffers are read in 1 byte chunks, which happens to be the size that the C++ standard ensures a `char` to have.

However, using void-pointers is more generic. It's a way for the function to tell you, "Just give me some data, don't worry about how I'll read it". The function can then cast the pointer and read the data in chunks or whatever size it likes.

Comment: you can read `char*` in chunks too. And I'll bash you on the head (really), if you ever request data this way in C++.

Comment: @Matthieu What so bad about it?

Comment: In C, this is nigh idiomatic, but 1/ C++ is built around type safety, while you can ignore it, there is a steep price to be paid (maintenance) if you do; 2/ Separating a buffer from its size is always awkward, even if you bypass type safety, you might at least do it in a way that you won't also bypass memory safety... Build a class around that buffer and its size, so you're sure the size does not go out of sync.

Comment: @Paul: it's OK for `memcpy`, but for any I/O purposes it's unsafe to take a `void*` because that lets the caller pass in an `unsigned char*` or `signed char*` instead of a `char*`. Yes, OK, everyone uses two's complement, which can in fact be reinterpreted that way, but the C++ standard *pretends* that not everyone does, and so any lack of safety related to that informs the standard, and also informs the style of code and interfaces designed to be "portable". The definition of "portable" as "works on any conforming implementation" may be excessively broad, but at least it's concise.

Comment: Anyway, I think that's part of why `basic_istream::read` takes a `charT*`, and hence `istream` takes a `char*`. It gives you that little (tiny) bit of extra type safety compared with the old C-style `fread` which takes `void*`.

Answer (score 1):

void * is used in C++ to express a pointer type to an unknown structure.

So I would use it whenever I have a pointer type where the code shouldn't know what is in there:

- memory allocation
- containers
- ...

Often void * mix quite well with template code to avoid template induced code bloat.

imagine you implement a

```
template <typename T>
class vector {
 /*stuff */
};
```

you can then create a template specialisation for T * which uses void pointers so the code doesn't get duplicated.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it avoids duplication? You're talking about in the output right? As far as I can see the code *will* be duplicated since there will still be code synthesized for every T still but there might be errors the compiler can't spot.

Comment: @awoodland: the methods of `<T*>` specialisation will `static_cast<>` every `T*` to `void*` and then call the corresponding `method on the `void*` specialisation. These `<T*>` methods will therefore be trivial and inlined, leaving only calls to the `<void*>` template methods.